# Get all routes defined in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I am using webformrouting in my asp.net c# application.

In my global.asax file i define a couple of routes.

My question is, how can i get a list of all routes defined from code behind (on a page)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access the `Routes` property on the `RouteTable`

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes;
```

Comment: sorry for sounding stupid, but how does that return me a list of all routes?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question correctly, but this will return a RouteCollection. This collection contains all the defined routes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.aspx

Comment: i get this when using your example: method all has 1 parameter but is invoked with 0 arguments

Comment: Oops, my mistake. You don't need the .All()

Comment: It may have been so easy in 2008 when originally asked. But now - there are collection routes inside the route and those are not so easily enumerated.

Answer (score 4):

I create a partialView to visualize these in the site to help me from time to time (debugging).

```
@{ 
    var routes = RouteTable.Routes;
}
@foreach (var route in routes)
{
    var r = (System.Web.Routing.Route)route;
    <h4>@r.Url</h4>
}
```